# I want to initialize the linearlayout in the XML view below after the recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I want to initialize the linearlayout in the XML view below after the recyclerview. But I couldn't find a solution.

XML CODE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
        
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/appcolor5"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/appcolor5"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/left_menu_item"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dergilinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/appcolor5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descdergi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by initialize?

Comment: I want it to appear after recyclerview @RalphDias

Comment: Try changing the parent layout to a LinearLayout or a ConstraintLayout and constrain your LinearLayout to the bottom of your recycler view